# Visual Studio 2010 Simple Form

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I've been searching, testing and trying a lot of things to create my project with Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

What I need is the same thing as Windows Form Application but ONLY in C++ (no managed stuff). So I guess I should be creating an MFC application. However, is there a way to design the main window? In the resources of the project, there are only the resources used by the main window, but it seems not possible to design (with the toolbox) the main window itself.

Am I missing something here? Anyone knows how to do this or point me to a good tutorial. I'm still searching for a solution, and I'll post it if I find it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: An MFC dialog based app is all you got.  Consider QT.

Comment: Just create a dialog-based app. It doesn't *have* to be MFC. You can do this using a resource editor and the plain Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a dialog-based app (as Hans wrote): The resource editor will let you add/move/size/configure controls to your dialog.

Or alternately, you can create a SDI MFC application and choose CFormView as the base class for the main view. This way, your main view (aka form) is a dialog that you can fill in using the resource editor the same way you would do with a dialog.